# Firestore security rules - using custom claims

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I just want to make sure I understand correctly custom claims, here is one example how I want to use them: in my app I associate each user to a unique user-friendly userid (like "Bill"), and some of my security rules use this id. The user info and profile are stored in a document /users/{user} where I also store the corresponding Firestore authentication id.

For instance: in the document /users/bill I have

```
  { firstname: "William"
    lastname: "Clinton"
    ...
    userid: "Bill"            // Case sensitive userid
    uid: "faergq34tfawefawef" // A valid Firestore authentication id }
```

Then I have some collections where I want to define the access based on this userid, for instance:

```
match /users/{user}/friends/{friend} {
  allow create, update: if request.auth.uid != null
    && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(user)).data.uid==request.auth.uid;
}
```

And with custom claims the rule could simply look like:

```
match /users/{user}/friends/{friend} {
  allow create, update: if request.auth.uid != null
    && request.auth.token.userid.lower() == user;
}
```

Much simpler and saves 1 read on each rule execution. Any feedback? Does this make sense? Just making sure I am not missing something before rewriting all my rules...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd ever want to use `userid` in a rule when it seems that the usual Firebase `uid` is just as unique, and always available in `request.auth.uid`.  I see `userid` as something that's only important for display purposes.

The purpose of custom claims is to attach data to a user account that grants it special privileges or permissions.  Typically people put a boolean in there grant "admin" access, or indicate some type of group membership.

A user ID is not really either of those things.  While it's not necessarily *wrong* to put a user ID in custom claims, I don't see what value it has here.  A user already has a unique ID with its Firestore UID - that should be the preferred way of checking the identity of the user.